# static pointer variable from another namespace is not working

Tags: c++, static, namespaces

In my project, I am having an issue in accessing the static pointer variable in another file within a namespace.
This static pointer variable is always returned as `NULL`.

The code structure as below:

**file1.hpp**

```
namespace myTestnamespace
{
    struct 
    {
        int i;
        int j;
    }myTest;

    static myTest* obj_instance = NULL;
    static float value = 0.0;
    void start();
    void stop();
    myTest* getInstance();
}
```

**file1.cpp**

```
#include "file1.hpp"
namespace myTestnamespace
{
    void start()
    {
        obj_instance = new myTest();
        value = 111.0f;
        obj_instance->i = 100;
        obj_instance->j = 200;
    }
    void stop()
    {
        delete obj_instance;
        value = 0.0;
    }
    myTest* getInstance()
    {
        return obj_instance;
    }
}
```

**file2.hpp**

```
#include "file1.hpp"
using namespace myTestnamespace;
```

The `start()` is called from another separate file directly.

**file2.cpp**

```
int main()
{
    int* pObj = myTestnamespace::getInstance();
    if (pObj  != NULL)
    {
        cout<< pObj->i <<  pObj->j;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<< "pObj is NULL";
    }
}
```

I am not getting the static variable properly. Always it is returned as `NULL`.
What may be the issue here?

Is there any problem with namespace?

Comment: `static myTest* obj_instance = NULL;` why would it be not NULL? You seem to expect that magically `start` is called, but why?

Comment: whats the purpose of the code? It looks too compilcated. If you want a singleton look up "Meyers singleton"

Comment: Maybe you should redesign before continuing, almost alway singleton is NOT needed (and creating a singleton that you cannot destroy, that's not very RAII friendly either). You might want to read up on dependency injection (and unit testability) first.
Globals and statics have a tendency to glue your whole codebase together and that will make it hard to refactor later. If you still think you need a singleton read this : [meyer's singleton](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/thread-safe-initialization-of-a-singleton) at least that doesn't leak (and can be threadsafely initialized).

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number
 The start() is called from another separate file directly.

Comment: What do you think `static` means in your **header** file?

Comment: "start() is called from another separate file directly" - Show us that in detail. Because one possible explanation for your issue is that `start` is not actually being called when you think it is. But without seeing how it's called, that leaves a gap where we can only guess.

Comment: Namespaces are not like classes. Static class member variables are not the same as static namespace variables. In fact, the global scope is *also* a namespace scope, so variables inside a namespace are handled exactly the same as any other global variables. Which means that every translation unit will have its own copy of the static variables. So it's not a singleton.

Comment: Don't put variable definitions in header files, it is almost always an error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are accessing the  `obj_instance` variable directly, however it is a private static variable in the `myTestnamespace namespace`. For this to work just access this `static` variable, you need to use the `getInstance()` function defined in the namespace.

An example code with the problem solved:

```
file2.cpp

#include "file1.hpp"
using namespace myTestnamespace;

int main()
{ 
     start(); // Calls the start() function to initialize the variable obj_instance
     myTest* pObj = getInstance(); // Gets the instance of the variable obj_instance
     

if (pObj != NULL)
{
    cout << pObj->i << " " << pObj->j;
}
else
{
    cout << "pObj is NULL";
}

stop(); // Calls the stop() function to free the memory allocated by obj_instance

return 0;
```

}

Eventually you will see the correct output with the values of `i` and `j` from the `myTest` structure or the message "pObj is NULL" if the `obj_instance` variable is still `NULL`.

Comment: What does “private” mean here?